# Projectile: how to exclude deep subdirectories by pattern?

Tags: projectile

Is it possible to exclude from a project all directories matching a pattern at other than the project root level? In my case, I want to exclude subdirectories (deeper than the project root level) with the name matching `split*`, for instance, exclude a path `<project_root>/egs/foo/exp/bar/split8`. These directories are autogenerated, and the number after "split" changes, so I cannot explicitly list them. Anything I tried in the `.projectile` file did not work.

Tracing [the code](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/master/projectile.el) suggests this is not likely possible, but I am still daring to ask in case I overlooked something.

Comment: Are you familiar with `ag`? It is a search utility like grep. You can make `ag` cache the project database instead of gitgrep or find. You can specify which files/folders to ignore in `ag`.

Comment: @kaushalmodi: Thanks, but in my case I need to look at files that are generated by scripts in addition to source code. So my "project" dynamically changes.

Comment: That should not matter as long as you know the name of the directory you need to ignore.

Comment: @kaushalmodi: Ah, interesting. I did not grok the idea at first, sorry. Is `ag` a command-line utility or emacs package? I seem to be unable to google up anything useful.

Comment: Search for *the silver searcher github*.  It is a command line utility like grep.

Comment: Have your tried customizing the variable `projectile-globally-ignored-directories`?